# Blueprint for DXA websites that can share schema and content and have there own

Tags: dxa, sites-9, blueprint, dxa2.2

**After importing the DXA 2.2 example website we created 2 websites in development.**

We want to setup it for two applications that can share content and has its own content.

000 Empty, 100 Master, 110 A DXA Type, 200 A Content, 400 A Website.

000 Empty, 100 Master, 110 B DXA Type, 200 B Content, 400 B Website.

- We use one language.
- Folder security is preferred instead of new publication

The questions are:

- what is a useful blueprint for this common data?
- is sharing common schema and data in 100 Master a best practise?
- can we put all content in Master?
- if schema differs for both appl then you have to localize schema in 110 and content in 200?

[image]

UPDATE 3-Nov-2020
We start with this BluePrint. It uses common content.

[image]

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for - you cannot modify the data format for a schema, even when localized (try it out, you'll see what I mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there are 5 levels in the DXA example BluePrint:

1. `000 Empty`. The BluePrint root, Not really empty (it contains CM default items), but doesn’t contain anything DXA-specific and is merely there to facilitate future BluePrint changes.
2. `100 Master`. This contains the DXA Schemas, TBBs and settings (Components). In general, no “real” content.
3. `110 Site Type`. Intended to act as Site Type (to facilitate the Site Wizard) and contains XPM Content and Page Types.
4. `200 Example Content`. This is the Content level of the BluePrint and typically where the Components are created.
5. `400 Example Site`. This is the Site level of the BluePrint; it is the Publication that actually gets published and typically where the Pages are created.

Note that there is no Publication prefixed with “300”, because the example BluePrint doesn’t cater for translations. That is: there is nothing stopping you from creating “300” level Publications (with content translations) and “500” level Publications for localized Sites, but this is just not included in the OOTB example BluePrint.

In your case, you don’t need translations, but you do want common/global and app-specific/local content.
I would create a similar BluePrint as for translations:

- Use a common “200” level Content Publication
- Use app-specific “300” level Content Publications (using the common Content Publication as parent)
- Let your Site Publications inherit from their respective “300” level Content Publication

As Nuno mentioned, you can’t change Schemas by localizing them (you can only translate the field labels in a Local Copy). If you have app-specific Schemas, you would have to create them in the “110” level Publications (the “Site Types”).

See also [the DXA documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/784837/696354/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/using-the-------------dxa-blueprint).